# How to create a tree view in uwp xaml

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview, uwp-xaml

hi guys I have created a Tree view but I can't print the content in the tree view
my code is
`

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeview" Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
         <TreeView.RootNodes >
             <TreeViewNode Content="colur">
                 <TreeViewNode.Children>
                     <TreeViewNode Content="blue"></TreeViewNode>
                     <TreeViewNode Content="green"></TreeViewNode>
                     <TreeViewNode Content="red"></TreeViewNode>
                 </TreeViewNode.Children>
             </TreeViewNode>
         </TreeView.RootNodes>
     </TreeView>
```

`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the UWP application can't find the `TreeViewNode` class as it is a WinUI control. Please use the [TreeView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.treeview?view=winui-2.8) from the WinUI library in your UWP aplication.

1. In the **Solution Explorer**, right click on your project name and select **Manage NuGet Packages**.
2. In the **NuGet Package Manager**, select the **Browse** tab and search for **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** or **WinUI**. Install which Windows UI Library NuGet Packages you want to use. I'm using WinUI 2.8.1
3. Add the **Windows UI (WinUI) Theme Resources** to your **App.xaml** file.

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
   ```
4. Add a reference to the WinUI package to both **XAML pages** and/or **code-behind pages**.

   `xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"`
5. Change your Xaml code to use the TreeView control from WinUI library.

Like this:

```
  <muxc:TreeView x:Name="treeview" Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes >
            <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="colur">
                <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="blue"></muxc:TreeViewNode>
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="green"></muxc:TreeViewNode>
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="red"></muxc:TreeViewNode>
                </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
            </muxc:TreeViewNode>
        </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
    </muxc:TreeView>
</Grid>
```